# Could not list layers for this store, an error occurred retrieving them: No enum constant org.geotools.mbtiles.MBTilesMetadata.t_type.BASELAYER

Tags: geoserver, mbtiles

I am trying to load my .mbtiles file in geoserver. I have installed the mbtiles plugin. But when I try to upload the file it gives me following error:

```
Could not list layers for this store, an error occurred retrieving them: No enum constant org.geotools.mbtiles.MBTilesMetadata.t_type.BASELAYER
```

I know I have to change the BASELAYER to OVERLAY but I have no idea how to do it.

Can anyone suggest how to do it?

Cheers,

Comment: can you turn logging up to geotools-developer and run the request again and paste in the relevant part of the log file